# Nvim config messes up the indentation

Tags: config, neovim

I have this nvim config, but there seems to be something off with it. Any time, where I'm using braces and think, that nvim will indent the ending brace on the next line, it does not, or rather, it seems to reset it. I don't know what it causing this behavior and I thought, that maybe someone from you guys can spot the error.

Here is a link to my dotfiles: https://github.com/KacperTKI/dotfiles

Thanks in advance!

I tried messing around with the smartindent and autoindent options, but nothing helped. I also added custom vim functions for automatically indenting, but I want to find the real cause of the issue and not hack around it.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 3):

for anyone wondering. I have found the issue. It was the language specific formatter for C++ that was causing it.

```
au FileType cpp set formatprg=clang-format | set equalprg=clang-format
```

For some reason setting it to clang-format has caused the indentation to reset everytime. Anyway, it's fixed now.